# Byte array in Python only accepts unsigned integers

Tags: python, arrays, binary, codec

I'm working on audio codecs in Python (yikes) using byte arrays to edit individual byte data from an audio file.

I have a certain encryption in mind that requires me to perform bit wise operations on single bytes stored in the byte-array.

One of those operations is the `~` operator (bitwise NOT) which essentially reverses the bit (`b'0001` becomes `b'1110`).

The problem is when you reference a single element of a byte array, it returns an int (does Python by default consider untyped 8 bit data integers?). Integers in Python are by default signed (I don't think unsigned integers even exist in Python).

When you try to perform bit-wise NOT on a byte in the byte-array, you get the following error:

```
>>> array[0] = ~array[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

This is because it expects an unsigned int between 0-255. How do I convert a signed int into an unsigned int such that the bits used to represent both values remain the same?

Cheers

Comment: I think numpy should provide unsigned ints. I would try np.array(array).astype(np.uint8)

Comment: "I have a certain encryption in mind" - are you writing your own crypto? [Please don't write your own crypto.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43274/)

Comment: Hahah no... I wouldn't ever try that... trying to emulate something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different operation for bit flipping.

E.g.:<sup>1</sup>

```
array[i] = 255 - array[i]
```

or also:

```
array[i] = 255 ^ array[i]
```

will flip **all** (i.e.: 8) bits.

---

<sup>1</sup> the math behind this can be worked out from [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) wikipedia page.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `256 - array[0]` ? Appreciate the quick response. Stuff like this makes me feel stupid hehe.

Comment: @JonathanMay: No. If `array[0]` is initially `0`, then `256 - array[0]` is `256`, but the desired output is `255`.

Comment: @JonathanMay: why don't you try it and see? `for i in range(256): print('{:08b} {:08b}'.format(i, 255-i))`

Comment: @JonathanMay: actually: `all([{'0':'1','1':'0'}[c] for c in f'{i:08b}']==list('{:08b}'.format(255-i)) for i in range(256))` == `True`

Comment: @user2357112 But `~0` is -1. So `256 + ~0` is `255`

Comment: @JonathanMay: `~0` gives `-1`, but this answer doesn't involve `~`.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is actually remarkably simple after playing around with a binary calculator a little bit.

Just subtract the magnitude of the SIGNED int from 256, to get the value of the UNSIGNED int with the same binary representation.

So,

`-23` signed would be `233` unsigned.

Hope this helps anyone else looking for a solution :)

EDIT: For those saying answer is `255 - array[0]`. In this case I'm looking for a way to go from post NOT'd int to its unsigned counter part. So I've already performed the bitwise NOT on the integer, now I'm just getting it back to a form that can be inputted into the byte-array.

So in the end it would look something like this:

```
tmp = ~array[0]
array[0] = 256 + tmp
```

or

```
array[0] = 256 - abs(tmp)
```

This gets me the correct answer :)

Comment: Not 256. 255. Subtracting from 256 changes the range from 0-255 to 1-256.

Comment: Or if you're already working with the output of `~`, then you need to add it to 256, not subtract.

Comment: If you take a number, say `-12`. In binary, that's `11110100`. If you then convert `11110100` into an unsigned int, you get `244`. Did I go wrong anywhere there?